# how export addresses into PATH for running pyspark in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Hi I have installed Spark and Python and Jupyter Notebook in Amazon AWS EC2 but when I run "jupyter notebook" in the command prompt it just provides an address for "jupyter notebook" when I open the jupyter notebook, I can't run pyspark commands. I just can run python commands.
I googled it and found these commands:

export SPARK_HOME=/home/ubuntu/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2

export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH

After executing them, when I typed "jupyter notebook" I access a "jupyter notebook" that can support pyspark.
However, when I close my commands prompt and logged in later, I have to type the above commands again to be able to have "pyspark" in the "jupyter notebook".
My question: how permanently save those variables in "PATH" of environment variable. And how can see all of the environment variables including the ones that I entered through above commands.

Answer (score 0):

It's can be a similar case for environment variables and your local terminal. To have some extra variables exported, you need to save those export commands in your EC2 machine `.bashrc` file

More details can be easily found on the Internet, for example [here](https://jeffmcneill.com/bashrc-bash_profile-path-on-ami/)